# Joining two table entities with @OneToOne annotation generate "cross join" while "inner join" expected

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, cross-join

I have OneToOne tables/entities Person and Employee: 
each employee has only one person and each person is attached to one and only one employee.
The generated query do tables join with "cross join" keyword while "inner join" would be more appropriate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_Person", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=255)
    private String EMail;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@Data
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_Employee", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String numero;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_Employee")
    private Person person;
}
```

Repository:

`public  interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository {
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE LOWER(e.person.name) LIKE CONCAT(LOWER(:name),'%')")
    List findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}`

Here is thes generated queries:

```
select employee0_.id_Employee as id_Emplo1_0_, employee0_.department as departme2_0_ 
from employee employee0_ 
cross join person person1_ 
where employee0_.id_Employee=person1_.id_Person 
and (lower(person1_.name) like concat(lower(?), '%'))
;
select person0_.id_Person as id_Perso1_2_0_, person0_.EMail as EMail2_2_0_, person0_.name as name3_2_0_ 
from person person0_ 
where person0_.id_Person=?
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the entity Employee, join column should be *id_Person*.
Apart from that, I'd recommend using Querydsl for a fine-grained control over your joins. Your query will look something like this:

```
query.from(employee).leftJoin(employee.person, person)
.where(person.name.lower().like(name.toLowerCase() + "%")).fetch();
```